# Specifying encoding in Popen

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, subprocess

In Python 3.6 you need to specify a string encoding in order to pass a string to the `communicate()` method.

One approach is to set `universal_newlines` to `True` which, it seems, does some platform-specific magic to set the input to string.

The other approach is to set `encoding=` to some value, though I cannot find a definitive list of legal values (it seems I could use `"utf-8"` or `"ascii"`.

Should I simply set `universal_newlines` and not worry about the encoding, or is there some reason to do something more specific?